# Getting this error when I want to install PyAutoIt

Tags: 18.04, python

When I wanted to install PyAutoIt with command using terminal :

```
pip install PyAutoIt
```

I get this error in terminal:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-9cAwZr/PyAutoIt/
```

Has someone had the same problem before, any suggestion would help out.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't install PyAutoIt on non-Windows platforms.

PyAutoIt provides an interface to [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). AutoIt only works on Microsoft Windows platform, so this applies to the python module as well. On the [website](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoIt/) environment is listed as Win32.